# G++ compiler failed to find headers required by iostream

Tags: c++, linux, g++, iostream

I'm trying to compile a simple c++ code which includes `<iostream>` header. Surprisingly I'm facing the error which i never faced before. Everything works fine if `<iostream>` header is removed.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation error:

```
$ g++ temp.cpp
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/stdint.h:9:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/cstdint:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:501,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from temp.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:26:2: error: #error This header should only be used with Microsoft compilers
 #error This header should only be used with Microsoft compilers
  ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/cerrno:42:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ext/string_conversions.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:6361,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from temp.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/errno.h:14:10: fatal error: crtdefs.h: No such file or directory
 #include <crtdefs.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

g++ version details:

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
```

If i remove the `<iostream>` header the code compiles. I think some of the headers are not found with in the include paths. But the error is very strange to me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Additional logs:

```
$ g++ -v temp.cpp
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/cc1plus -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE test.cpp -quiet -dumpbase test.cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase test -version -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -o /tmp/ccueFKYa.s
GNU C++14 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) version 7.4.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 7.4.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.1, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.19-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/7
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7
 /usr/include/c++/7/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++14 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) version 7.4.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 7.4.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.1, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.19-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 38816e3807cdcb3c59571e251bd6c090
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/stdint.h:9:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/cstdint:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:501,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:26:2: error: #error This header should only be used with Microsoft compilers
 #error This header should only be used with Microsoft compilers
  ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/cerrno:42:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ext/string_conversions.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:6361,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/errno.h:14:10: fatal error: crtdefs.h: No such file or directory
 #include <crtdefs.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Thanks!

Comment: what are the header files in `/usr/local/include`? Apparently these header files are wrong. I don't currently know how to configure the include path where gcc searches for header files. As a workaround you can try to (backup and) remove the files from `/usr/local/include`.

Comment: It seems your header files are entangled. Unlikely, it is a serious GCC bug.

Comment: in this case I simply would try do uninstall and install the gcc packages. But maybe some other package has dropped some wrong header files somewhere. Have you installed something locally without distro package manager. Having wrong things in /usr/local...?

Comment: Did you install anything manually, outside the package manager? Either directly into `/usr/locale` or with something like `make install`? It seems you installed something outside the Ubuntu package manager to `/usr/local/` that doesn't belong there. There should be no standard library headers in `/usr/local/include` except if you intend to overwrite the ones provided by your OS/distribution and that is unlikely.

Comment: Did you install a [cross compiler for windows](http://retroshare.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Ubuntu_cross_compilation_for_Windows) on your ubuntu? It looks like you installed some sort of cross compiler and are using these "wrong" libraries for your native OS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have something unexpected in /usr/local/. Try uninstalling Microsoft® compilers, SDK, headers, etc. If you have no such packages, remove the offending files from /usr/local/include/ (or just move the whole directory into a backup).

Comment: I mistakenly installed a library include files at `/usr/local/include` location which has a header `stdint.h`. So g++ is picking this header instead of the actual one and because of that `crtdefs.h` is getting included. Thanks for the help.